# GWT : Focus goes away when i edited the text box and save it

Tags: java, gwt, setfocus, lost-focus

I have one link on click of that link one can edit the name of that link in the text box.

[image]

After editing save and close options are there. after saving this the focus goes out from the link i need that focus must be stay there on the link.

[image]

I am using

```
Scheduler.get().scheduleDeferred(new ScheduledCommand() {
public void execute () {
    link.setFocus(true);
}
});
```

for the link but it will focus for a second only not permanently to that link.
Looking for solution.

Thanks..!!

Comment: did you try `setFocus(true)` on click of the save and close option?

Comment: yes i am using this only

Comment: use it after `hide()` of edit panel inside save/close `clickhandler`. would be much better if you post some code here.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code inside your close and save button clickhandler.

```
Scheduler.get().scheduleDeferred(new ScheduledCommand() {
    public void execute () {
        link.setFocus(true);
    }
});.
```

Comment: yes. setFocus in GWT i am always using inside the scheduler.get().....!! This is not working

Comment: using this code inside (not outside) the `clickhandler` of your close and save button, i don't see a point the link to lose its focus. I have faced similar issues but this works fine for me.